# Issue with PHP sessions and manager

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection, session-management

I am attempting to create a session manager for my application to access multiple methods on sessions easily and in a more flexible way, however for some reason I am getting an error every so often which I believe may be related to the garbage collector, is this due to how I have created the session manager or another issue?

Error:

```
PHP Notice: Unknown: ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\) failed: No error (0)
```

Within the constructor of my session manager I have this code:

```
    if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){

        self::startSession(); // returns session_start();

    }
```

I have read about the web about related issues but wasn't sure if it was the same issue as others were having related to modify permission on the web server or was related to my specific way of handling sessions.

Comment: Check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/696066/php-on-windows-ps-files-cleanup-dir-error

Comment: Is there anything that seems to be incorrect with my session manager? Or is it definitely a permission related issue?